# How can I list related branches in git log

Tags: git, git-log

I am looking for a possibility to show the history of a given file together with the information in which branch the given commit is in.

Given this git repositority:

```
$ git log --graph --all --decorate=full --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit 
* 3b116ab (refs/heads/br2) x
| * 8777a0a (HEAD -> refs/heads/br1, refs/heads/branch) g
| * 9be1f38 d
|/ 
| * 3a30d9c (refs/heads/master) d
| * e678c2f c
|/  
* faa3666 b
* 03ea6ad a
```

I need the history of a given file

```
$ git log --graph --all --decorate=full --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit -- a
* 9be1f38 d
| * e678c2f c  
|/  
* faa3666 b
* 03ea6ad a
```

and the information in which branch which commit is in

```
$ git branch -a
* br1
  br2
  branch
  master

$ git branch -a --contains 9be1f38
* br1
  branch

$ git branch -a --contains e678c2f
  master

$ git branch -a --contains faa3666
* br1
  br2
  branch
  master
```

combined in one overview, something like

```
$ git magical-command
+ refs/heads/br2
| + HEAD -> refs/heads/br1, refs/heads/branch
| * 9be1f38 d
|/ 
| + refs/heads/master
| * e678c2f c
|/  
* faa3666 b
* 03ea6ad a
```

Of course in reality there would be much more commits not changing my file "a".

I think that might be not so unusual but I did not find anything like this. So any hint would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want, but a misconception needs clearing up first, don't skip this: commits can be ancestors of any number of commits, whatever  names you're using in your local repo is irrelevant. Branch names refer to currently-particular commits in the history graph but they're *strictly* local; any correspondence among branch names used in any two repos is a matter of convenience or coincidence, the `WIP` branch in your repo from last night is almost certainly not related to the `WIP` branch in Sam's.

The command you're looking for is

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --ancestry-path --simplify-by-decoration --branches ^9be1f38
```

and those first three args are so useful I have

```
git config --global alias.lgdo '!f(){ git log --graph --decorate --oneline "${@---all}"; }; f'
```

so  `git lgdo` gives a full overview, `git lgdo @` gives a current-checkout history, and so on.

Your command would then be

```
git lgdo --ancestry-path --simplify-by-decoration --branches ^9be1f38
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I just modified it slightly to `git log --graph --decorate --oneline  --simplify-by-decoration --branches  -- a` which gives exactly what I wanted!